# Appending html/text to existing html using Python's email package

Tags: python, html, email

I'm writing some code to send a body of html code with embedded images to many recipients. The text/images will be identical, however I want to include an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email
that will be unique for each recipient. Currently, I'm recreating the entire msg for each email which seems inefficient, seeing as the only difference between each msg is a link at the bottom (especially since the emails contain 4 images and 2 attachments).

I'm unable to separate the html portion of the msg, as it's required before the images can be embedded. Is there any way to append another piece of html/text to the bottom of a msg, after the initial html has been set?

Here's an example from https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html that is nearly identical to my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import smtplib

from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.utils import make_msgid

# Create the base text message.
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = "Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner"
msg['From'] = Address("Pepé Le Pew", "pepe", "example.com")
msg.set_content("""\
Salut!

Cela ressemble à un excellent recipie[1] déjeuner.

[1] http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718

--Pepé
""")

# Add the html version.  This converts the message into a multipart/alternative
# container, with the original text message as the first part and the new html
# message as the second part.
asparagus_cid = make_msgid()
msg.add_alternative("""\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Salut!</p>
    <p>Cela ressemble à un excellent
        <a href="http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Roasted-Asparagus-Epicurious-203718">
            recipie
        </a> déjeuner.
    </p>
    <img src="cid:{asparagus_cid}" />
  </body>
</html>
""".format(asparagus_cid=asparagus_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')
# note that we needed to peel the <> off the msgid for use in the html.

# Now add the related image to the html part.
with open("roasted-asparagus.jpg", 'rb') as img:
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'jpeg',
                                     cid=asparagus_cid)

## MY CHANGES
emails = ["foo@bar.com", "bar@foo.com"]
for email in emails:
    # append_text(email)
    msg["To"] = email
    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
    with smtplib.SMTP('localhost') as s:
        s.send_message(msg)
```